# What is/are the java/javascript equivalent methods for commands in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, jmeter

Today is my 2nd day playing with selenium.  Out of curiosity, is there a site with selenium commands and their equivalent javascript/java method?

I'm trying to create a jmeter test where it takes a Webdriver sampler and executes it.  I got some commands from this [site](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler).  About halfway down, they showed how selenium captured data can be converted to WebDriver format (screenshot below) [image: sample cmds])

This is a screenshot of my working "script" from selenium.

[image: our selenium cmds]

I had tried the sample commands/scripts from this website [here](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) and they worked.  However, I couldn't get my cmds from my script working because I couldn't figure out the equivalent js/java method to use.  For example, I have a "waitforElementPresent" command in my "script".  However, I couldn't find a waitforElementPresent or a addSelection method in the api (link found [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/allclasses-noframe.html)).

Is there a site out there that shows us which methods to use for which selenium command?  Am I crazy and shouldn't be doing exploratory exercises like this?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is even easier way:

1. Open your recorded testcase in Selenium IDE'
2. Click File - Export TestCase As...
3. Select desired language in which you want to learn (my assumption is Java - JUnit 4 - Webdriver)
4. Open the file in your peferred IDE or text editor
5. You will see all steps transferred into code, with it correct equivalents

Answer (score 1):

on http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/ you can find a lot of information on the java commands/methods of selenium.

If you want to learn more about webDriver I would recommend to read the following documents http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Just start at the beginning and practice with small pieces of code.